# Particles keep going are appearing on the bottom side of the model!

Tags: particles

I have been using Grasswald (Even without it this happens with normal particles as well) to create grass on this rocky field but for some reason portions of the particles appear underneath it, facing to the bottom.

I have tried weight painting it and assigning the group in particles settings, then I used a solidify modifier to add a lot of thickness and tried weight paint once again but no luck.

I then ALSO tried a subdivision surface with the thickness and without, that did not work either. The closest I got was adding a 1 to the Z in Veclocity selection of the particle settings that makes the button ones face the right side but for some reason the ones that were already on the right side get bigger in size and slightly denser. Please help me. I'm on the 3rd day of trying to fix this I'm out of options at this point.

---

Here are pictures to show what is going on.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please use the built in tools to add images to your posts instead of adding links to external sites. If those links ever break the information will be lost for future visitors with the same question.

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: Most likely your normals are inverted so it grows in the wrong direction